# Why is Laravel Voyager BREAD Accessor not returning formated date?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, voyager

When trying to format date with laravel accessor everything works fine.

```
public function getDueDateAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

But when I use Laravel Voyager BREAD Browse accessor

```
public function getDueDateBrowseAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ErrorException(code: 0): Data missing at vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:594
```

Comment: have you tried using `formatLocalized()` instead of `format()`

Comment: Yes, it says Call to a member function formatLocalized() on null. On return $value it outputs the date. On gettype($value) again it says null value. Same thing happens when I try to gettype($this->due_date)

Comment: it can occur when you are calling `getDueDateBrowseAttribute()` for multiple values but $value is null for some of them, does $value has always non null value

Comment: it aways has a non null value